# Flask SQLAlchemy Connection Pooling not working

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, postgresql-9.4

I have the following situation :

config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://a:a@localhost/a'
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 5
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
```

models.py

```
class account_map(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'account_map'
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_key_type = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    account_key_value = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import models

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/account/<int:account_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_account(account_id):
    account = models.account_map.query.get(account_id)
    if account:
        return jsonify(account.as_dict())
    return jsonify(error=404, message=str("Not found"), timestamp=datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow())), 404


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

To check how many connections are opened:

```
 SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = '...';
```

No matter how many requests are performed ( I've used JMeter with 25 concurrent users ) there is just only one connection in the database opened, and the Throughput is almost the same as like I'm using just one thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I have found out why i don't see many connection is Postgresql : Flask is single threaded by default. It is needed to specify 
   `threaded = True` 
when you start the application. SQLAlchemy connection pooling is working.